# Ruby on Rails: looping through records, but don't show record from current id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm able to search through nearby records based on latitude and longitude from geocoder gem, but how do I not show the record that I'm looking at now?

If I'm in a project show with `localhost:3000/project/san-diego` (a location San Diego, US), and I do nearby search through

```
# controller
@project = Project.friendly.find(params[:id])
@nearby = Project.near([@project.latitude, @project.longitude], 50, :order => 'distance')

# view
<% @nearby.each do |n| %>
  <span><%= n.title_name %></span>
<% end %>
```

How do I not display the current record, but all other records that are nearby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using geocoder, you can simply do this:

```
# controller
@project = Project.friendly.find(params[:id])
@nearby = @project.nearbys(50)

# view
<% @nearby.each do |n| %>
  <span><%= n.title_name %></span>
<% end %>
```

Notice the `nearbys` method. This finds **other** of the same object within the given distance (50 miles). In this case, it will find other `Project`s.

This method is explained in more detail on the Geocoder docs page: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Comment: This is nice. Specific, but nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip it, as a general solution.

```
<% @nearby.each do |n| %>
  <% next if n == @project %>
  <span><%= n.title_name %></span>
<% end %>
```